# How to obfuscate classes present in a package by proguard Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I want to obfuscate some class files after ProGuard implemented.

Like I want to hide or obfuscation some classes name and members in a particular package. So that these will not be understandable after decompiling the application.

Example: I want to obfuscate classes present in package `com.myapp.serverCall`

How can I do this? 
Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can preserve all classes except the ones in some packages with an option like

```
-keep class !com.myapp.serverCall.** { *; }
```

The exclamation mark means "not these classes", thus only matching all remaining classes. The asterisk between parentheses means "all fields and methods".